# javascript - Promise.all freezes UI

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I am modifying one plugin to add a new feature to it. The plugin uses `Promise.all` as below:

```
Promise.all([
                coreUtils.promisify(_(this).fetch, this.buildRequest()),
                fetchDataIds.call(this)
            ])
            .then(this.onFetchSuccess.bind(this))
            .catch(this.onFetchError.bind(this));
```

This works fine without adding a support for the new feature.

Ok that's fine. But when I add multi-selectbox as a part of new feature, I've to call `Promise.all` each time item is selected in selectbox. This works fine sometimes and sometimes not. The UI freezes mostly when I select/deselect items in selectbox quickly. If I do in slow pace (in normal speed), it works fine.

**Update:**

The async method is `(_(this).fetch)`:

```
fetch: function (request) {
                    return usersService.get(request);
                },



function mockGet(request) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var start = request.offset,
                    end = start !== undefined ? request.offset + request.limit : undefined,
                    sortDirection = request.sortDir === 'asc' ? 1 : -1,
                    responseData = data;

                // logic to filter and sort data goes here

                var res = {
                    items: start !== undefined ? responseData.slice(start, end) : responseData,
                    total: responseData.length
                };
                resolve(coreUtils.clone(res, true));
            }, 500);
        });
    }

buildRequest: function () {
            return {
                sortAttr: this.getSortAttribute(),
                sortDir: this.getSortDirection(),
                limit: this.getPageLimit(),
                offset: this.getPageOffset(),
                pageIndex: this.getPageIndex(),
                filters: this.getFilters()
            };
        },

 function fetchDataIds() {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var dataIds = this.getDataInfoById();

        if (dataIds !== undefined) {
            return Promise.resolve(dataIds);
        }

        return coreUtils.promisify(_(this).getAllIds)
            .then(function (ids) {
                // initialize the selection to none selected
                var itemSelectedByIdMap = {};
                ids.forEach(function (idValue) {
                    itemSelectedByIdMap[idValue] = {selected: false};
                });

                setDataInfoById.call(this, itemSelectedByIdMap);
                setSelectionLevel.call(this, SelectionLevels.NONE, true);

                return itemSelectedByIdMap;
            }.bind(this));
    }
```

This is all the code. Logic to filter and sort is without any `Promise`.

**Possible Solution**
 I removed setTimeout from mockGet function and it works without freezing UI. Currently everything is done at client side. And so I am not sure whether I will get same performance once I call REST API.

**How do I resolve this issue of UI freeze with `Promise.all` ? Is there any workaround or is there any alternative ?**

Comment: `Promise.all()` is probably not your problem, but the (async) methods you call there.

Comment: @Sirko I've added the code of async method which has Promise as well.

Comment: Is this the actual code or is there more in place of "logic to filter ..." ?

Comment: @Sirko this is the actual code. logic to filter and sort is without Promise. uses filter and sort functions only. I've added code of all three methods called inside `Promise.all`.

Comment: I'd assume that your sort and filter run on to large a datasets. did you do some timing on how long that sort and filter takes?

Comment: @Sirko Dataset is of 1000 objects. it took 0.10500000000320142 to 1.5499999999992724 milliseconeds, if I do like select an item and wait for the response before selecting second item. But if I select items quickly, the UI freezes at any point of time.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. You could use the dev tools profiler to see, where JS spends the time, when the browser freezes.

Comment: @Sirko I removed `setTimeout` from mockGet function and it works without freezing UI. Currently everything is done at client side. And so I am not sure whether I will get same performance once I call REST API. May I know your input on this ?

Comment: as anything to do with Promises is asynchronous, I doubt the issue is with `Promise.all` - and to be honest, I can't see how that first snippet of code is at all relevant

Comment: Does `coreUtils.promisify()` return a promise?  Usually, promisifying an interface is a synchronous operation and fast so there is no need to use or return a promise  and you only do it once at startup time (at least that's how it works with the Bluebird promise library).  If it doesn't return a promise, there's no reason to be passing it to `Promise.all()`.